# Append values in new column based on 2 different condition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a sample data set which is similar to the one defined below.

```
dict_1 = {'Id' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
         'boolean_val' : [True, False, True, False, True, False],
         "sal" : [1000, 2000, 1500, 2500, 3500, 4500]}

test = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
test.head(10)
```

I have to create 2 new columns in test dataframe i.e. output_True & output_False based on given conditions:
a) If Id[0] == Id[1] & boolean_val = True then put sal[0](Because this is the value when boolean_val = True) in output_True else "NA".
b) If Id[0] == Id[1] & boolean_val = False then put sal[1](Because this is the value when boolean_val = False) in output_False else "NA".
c) If Id[0] 1= Id[1] & boolean_val == True then put sal value of that row in output_True else if Id[0] 1= Id[1] & boolean_val == False then put sal value of that row in output_False.

If I have not properly framed my question then please check below dataframe output and I want my output to be similar to output_True & output_False as shown below.

```
dict_1 = {'Id' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
         'boolean_val' : [True, False, True, False, True, False],
         "sal" : [1000, 2000, 1500, 2500, 3500, 4500],
         "output_True" : [1000, "NA", 1500, "NA", 3500, "NA"],
         "output_False" : [2000, "NA", 2500, "NA", "NA", 4500]}

output_df = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
output_df.head(10)
```

I have tried using np.where() & list comprehension but my output data is not showing me correct value. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Why you always comparing `Id[0] == Id[1]`? And I think your `output_true` and `output_false` combined should give you `sal`. Am I right?

Comment: So for 1st iter it will compare Id[0]==Id][1] and for 2nd Iter Id[1] ==ID[2] and so on. And Yes  output_true and output_false combined should give you sal

Comment: in your condition c) , what you mean by If Id[0] 1= Id[1]  ?  what is that 1

Answer (score 0):

Use loc to assign your values for the boolean column. For the second condition you can use `.shift()` and compare your Id[0] == Id[1] values and sum based on that:

```
dict_1 = {'Id' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
         'boolean_val' : [True, False, True, False, True, False],
         "sal" : [1000, 2000, 1500, 2500, 3500, 4500]}

test = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
test

    Id  boolean_val sal
0   1   True    1000
1   1   False   2000
2   2   True    1500
3   2   False   2500
4   3   True    3500
5   4   False   4500

cond1 = test.boolean_val
test.loc[cond1, 'output_True'] = test.sal


cond2 = (test.Id.shift(-1).eq(test.Id))
test['output_False'] = np.nan
test.loc[cond2, 'output_False'] = test['sal'] + test['output_True']
test

    Id  boolean_val sal output_True output_False
0   1   True    1000    1000.0  2000.0
1   1   False   2000    NaN     NaN
2   2   True    1500    1500.0  3000.0
3   2   False   2500    NaN     NaN
4   3   True    3500    3500.0  NaN
5   4   False   4500    NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get your desired output:

```py
df = test.pivot(index='Id', columns='boolean_val', values='sal')
df = df.assign(boolean_val=df.loc[:,True].notna()).set_index('boolean_val', append=True)
df = df.rename(columns={True:'output_True', False:'output_False'})[['output_True', 'output_False']]

output_df = test.join(df, on=['Id','boolean_val'])
for col in ('output_True', 'output_False'):
    output_df[col] = np.where(output_df[col].isna(), "NA", output_df[col].astype(pd.Int64Dtype()))
```

Output:

```
   Id boolean_val   sal output_True output_False
0   1        True  1000        1000         2000
1   1       False  2000          NA           NA
2   2        True  1500        1500         2500
3   2       False  2500          NA           NA
4   3        True  3500        3500           NA
5   4       False  4500          NA         4500
```

Explanation:

- use `pivot()` to create an intermediate dataframe `df` with `True` and `False` columns containing the corresponding `sal` values for each `Id`
- add a `boolean_val` column which contains `True` unless a given row's `True` column is `NaN`
- set `Id, boolean_val` as the index for `df`
- rename the `True` and `False` columns as `output_True` and `output_False` and swap their positions (to match the desired output)
- use `join()` to create `output_df` which is `test with added columns` output_True`and`output_False`
- replace `NaN` with the string `"NA"` and change `sal` values from float to int in `output_True` and `output_False`.